# Where can I get Python VTE bindings for the Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, python

I'm trying to comiple Guake top-down terminal (guake.org) in Mac OS X. I've met a bunch of dependency issues while ./configure phase, but now I'm completely stuck with the following dependency issue:

```
checking for the python-vte package... no
configure: error: cannot import Python module "vte".
    Please check if you have python-vte installed. The error was:
    No module named vte
```

I've installed python, pygtk and vte via Homebrew but can't find anything related to python-vte, pip doesn't give me any suitable candidates. I've spent a lot of time while have been googling how to resolve this dependency and didn't find any references of python VTE bindings sources but saw many prebuilt packages for other OSes (http://packages.debian.org/ru/sid/python-vte).

Did anybody meet this issue before or just knows how to resolve it?
Thanks.

PS: Sorry for my intermediate English..

Answer (score 1):

Macport has it. You may install MacPort and do a

```
sudo port install vte
```

NB: Installing vte trough MacPort install a new python in `/opt/local/` and vte gets installed in `/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gtk-2.0`

Comment: However - don't mix macports and homebrew, choose one or the other.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this via homebrew easily enough with:

```
brew install vte
```